# Excel update datarange of graph macro

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I have a big spreadsheet with a lot of data in it, now at the end of every month I make a graphic which contains all the data of the last year.

E.g.: It's the end of May so my old graph showed all the data from 04-30-2013 till 04-30-2014. and after running the macro it would contain the data from 05-31-2013 till 05-31-2014.

I use the date, availability and 10d MAV column for my data as well as the column headers for my labels

[image: graph]
[image: data]

Now I was looking for a macro which basically updates the datarange whenever I run the macro to match my example in the first part of the post.
Or something that would simplify my work as I have about 36 graphs I have to update manually every month and it usually takes quite a while to get all of them updated, and certainly if I have to let other people update it with less knowledge of excel, it would be very helpful if there would be an easier way to do this than having to update everything manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VBA below will do the task for you. There are three separate subs:

- removeSeries clears an existing chart
- populateChart adds a series to a chart
- test displays how the two functions above work (assuming dates are in column A, and values in columns B and C)

The sub populateChart requires a number of parameters that might require explanation:

- StartDate: format as #MM/DD/YYYY#
- EndDate: format as #MM/DD/YYYY#
- DateRange: range on worksheet where your array of dates is placed
- ValueRange: range on worksheet where your array of values is placed
- Chart: a chart object
- series_index: If you're adding more than one series, use 1 for the first, 2 two for the second, etc.

```
Sub removeSeries(Chart As Chart)
    For Each s In Chart.SeriesCollection
        s.Delete
    Next s
End Sub

Sub populateChart(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, DateRange As Range, ValueRange As Range, Chart As Chart, series_index As Integer)

    Dim first_row As Integer
    Dim last_row As Integer
    Dim ws_name As String

    'find first row
    For Each c In DateRange.Rows
        If DateValue(c.Value) >= StartDate Then
            first_row = c.Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c

    'find last row
    For Each c In DateRange.Rows
        If DateValue(c.Value) = EndDate Then
            last_row = c.Row
            Exit For
        ElseIf DateValue(c.Value) > EndDate Then
            last_row = c.Row - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c

    'get name of worksheet
    ws_name = Chart.Parent.Parent.Name

    'add series and axis labels to chart
    Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Chart.SeriesCollection(series_index).Values = "=" & ws_name & "!" & ValueRange.Rows(first_row & ":" & last_row).Address
    Chart.SeriesCollection(series_index).XValues = "=" & ws_name & "!" & DateRange.Rows(first_row & ":" & last_row).Address

End Sub

Sub test()
    removeSeries ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

    populateChart #4/1/2014#, #4/30/2014#, ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row), _
    ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B" & ActiveSheet.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row), ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart, 1

    populateChart #4/1/2014#, #4/30/2014#, ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row), _
    ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & ActiveSheet.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row), ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart, 2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than using a macro, you could try applying a filter to the data.  In my experience, Excel is pretty good at automagically updating the data used in a chart when you change the selection you've made in your filter.  So for instance when moving from May to June, you would deselect May from the Date column and select June instead (if dates are formatted properly, Excel should give you a hierarchic list of years then months).